# Issue IsolatedStorageFileStream while trying to create any kind of file

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a very wierd problem with `IsolatedStorageFileStream` in my WP7 project.  I always get an error like "**Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream**".

Here is my code (2 cases):

**1º:**

```
void camera_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    var imageBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
    e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("Fotos"))
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Fotos");


         IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("foto." + DateTime.Now.Date + "jpeg");

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

          bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    e.ChosenPhoto.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    imgField.Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);

    thumbnail = imageBytes;
    base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

**2º:**

```
void camera_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    var imageBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
    e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("Fotos"))
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Fotos");


        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"Shared/foto." + DateTime.Now.Date + "jpeg", FileMode.CreateNew, myIsolatedStorage);

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    e.ChosenPhoto.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    imgField.Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);

    thumbnail = imageBytes;
    base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

Can anyone tell WHY this code does not work, and an example of this site works: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Captured-Image?

Comment: You've given a lot of code - which method call failed?

Comment: What is the filename you generate? Does it have any invalid characters?

Comment: The method call that failed was this line

IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"Shared/foto." + DateTime.Now.Date + "jpeg", FileMode.CreateNew, myIsolatedStorage);

But i managed to concatenate the string name before using it in the overload method, guess it's an issue about WP7 programming?

In the end it worked well :), thanks for answers guys ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages from IsolatedStorage are note very helpful. If you try to open a file that doesn't exist, for example, you will get this same message. Its hard to guess what the exact problem is in your code without knowing exactly where you are getting the exception, but If I had to guess I would say that the cause is trying to generate the filename like this:

```
@"Shared/foto." + DateTime.Now.Date + "jpeg"
```

I'm not sure exactly how the date is getting converted to a string, it would depend on the locale, but my guess is that it is not creating a valid filename.

Comment: Actually it create a valid filename but it was not concatenating the date with the rest of the string, in the end it worked building the string filename before using it in the method.